# What is a good schema for naming screenshots in selenium webdriver + capyabara

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara, screenshot, webpage-screenshot

First pass: I name my screenshot "x".

Obviously that minimal setup only allows for 1 screenshot

I want to name the screenshots in a way that makes them unique and also reflect the usage.

I can make the filenname fairly unique with

```
output_directory = 'screenshots'
time = Time.new
page.save_screenshot("#{output_directory}/#{time}.png")
```

It's a bit ugly but I get

```
$ ls screenshots/

'019-04-13 07:07:50 -0400.png''
```

What would be good format to use that would meet the requirements of both unique and also descriptive.  Could I include the scenario description somehow?

How could I end up with something like:

```
scenario_decsription_2019_04_19-08_55_20
```

Comment: Ask ten people and you’ll get ten answers. Personally, I would use emoji: `.png`. Voted to close as primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

The RSpec test definition methods and hooks (`scenario`, `before`, `after`, etc) all receive an optional parameter which is the test example itself. This allows you to get the description of the test, etc for use in naming your file

```
scenario "my test" do |example|
  ...
  page.save_screenshot("#{example.full_description}.png")
end
```

Obviously you could transform the description in any way you want (convert spaces to underscores, etc).

Note: you may also want to look at `Capybara.save_path` which specifies what directory screenshots are stored in, if you don't want to prepend `screenshots/` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
scenario "#{scenario = 'user_clicks_the_dropdown'}" do
  output_directory = 'screenshots'
  time = Time.new
  suffix = time.to_s(:db).gsub(/[\:\.\_\s]/,'_')
  page.save_screenshot("#{output_directory}/#{scenario}_#{suffix}.png")
end
```